# Shift JSON based on value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a **JSON** as below

```
{"businessregistered":[
{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-07"},{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-08"},    
{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-09"},{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-10"},
{"busiRegCount":"3","newdate":"2012-10-11"},{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-12"},
{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-13"},{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-14"},
{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-15"},{"busiRegCount":"1","newdate":"2012-10-16"},
{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-17"},{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-18"},
{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-19"},{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-20"},
{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-21"},{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-22"}
],"businessactive":[],"resellerregistered":[],"reselleractive":[],"campaignregistered":
[],"campaignactive":[],"campaignexpiring":[],"revenuegenerated":[],"registrationpasscode":
[],"topuppasscode":[],"keywordmatched":[]}
```

and What I **need** is

```
{"businessregistered":[
{"busiRegCount":"3","newdate":"2012-10-11"},{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-12"},
{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-13"},{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-14"},
{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-15"},{"busiRegCount":"1","newdate":"2012-10-16"},
{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-17"},{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-18"},
{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-19"},{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-20"},
{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-21"},{"busiRegCount":"0","newdate":"2012-10-22"}
],"businessactive":[],"resellerregistered":[],"reselleractive":[],"campaignregistered":
[],"campaignactive":[],"campaignexpiring":[],"revenuegenerated":[],"registrationpasscode":
[],"topuppasscode":[],"keywordmatched":[]}
```

I need to start JSON from where I am getting `busiRegCount > 0` in PHP...

Please **HELP**

Comment: Decode to an array, sort the array, encode it back to JSON.

Comment: After earning 3K rep point, you should have to show your tried code.

Comment: I need to remove those values...So sort wont help me...

Comment: Nobody wants to diff those strings. Please give us a simpler example of your input/output.

Comment: Oh, you mean you want to *filter* all values before the first `> 0` value? Then *decode to an array, filter, encode it back to JSON.*

Comment: If I sort with busiRegCount, newdate with 2012-10-07 will still remain...I need to remove that element

Comment: I need something in which I dont have to loop through complete JSON and check the values....

Comment: @Wazzzy No array manipulation without loops...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to first decode the json, then repeatedly throw away data, then return it to json

```
$data = json_decode($json);

while(count($data->businessregistered) AND $data->businessregistered[0]->busiRegCount == 0) {
    array_shift($data->businessregistered);
}

$json = json_encode($data);
```

(assuming $json contains the json data)

Comment: Your `while` is going to need a `count($data->businessregistered)` as well, in case nothing is > 0, so it'd be `while (count($data->businessregistered) && $data->businessregistered[0]->busiRegCount == 0) {`

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1 but can I get something other than that where I dont need to loop through....

Comment: You're going to have to apply some filter or loop to throw away the top items, another approach is what @deceze has

Comment: @MarkOrmston good call, edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$array['businessregistered'] = array_filter($array['businessregistered'], function ($i) {
    static $keep = false;
    return $keep = $keep || $i['busiRegCount'] > 0;
});
$json = json_encode($array);
```

Comment: I'll point out that @duellsy's answer is potentially a lot more efficient, since he stops as soon as the desired value is found. `array_filter` always goes through *all* values. It usually won't make a lot of difference though, I'd go with the more readable (in your opinion) version.